# HotKey to trigger Ant Design Select to begin search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hotkeys

I am using 'react-hotkeys-hook' and using my hotkey works (can see log in console through onFocus()). Goal is to have a hotkey which opens and adds the cursor to the Select component. (Using ant design - 'antd')

The issue I have is when I trigger the hotkey no event is passed to the onFocus obviously - how do I pass to onFocus the event so that it works just the same as if I were to click on it? Or should I go about this a different way. I have tried using the open={true or false} inside the Select component and this works but does not add the cursor!

```
    useHotkeys('shift+p', () => onFocus());

    const hotKeyOpenSearch = () => {
    // pass searchbar event here?
        onFocus()
        console.log('hotkey shift+p')
    } 

    const onFocus = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
    }

    return (
        <Select
            showSearch
            style={{ width: searchW, paddingLeft: searchP }}
            dropdownStyle={{ zIndex: 9999 }}
            placeholder=" Fuzzy Search"
            optionFilterProp="children"
            onChange={onChange}
            onFocus={onFocus}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onSearch={onSearch}
        >
    </Select>
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, but `onFocus` is for receiving events only; you cannot call that method in any way that is going to programmatically re-focus the select component. However, [there is a `.focus()` method exposed by `antd`](https://ant.design/components/select/#Select-Methods) that you can call with your hotkey, but it requires getting a reference to the mounted component. Here is a working solution:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useHotkeys } from "react-hotkeys-hook";
import { Select } from "antd";

export default function App() {
  useHotkeys('shift+p', () => {
    // kind of hackish, but without timeout,
    // the hotkey will be sent to select input
    setTimeout(() => {
      selectRef.current.focus();
    }, 20);
  });

  // This will hold reference to `<Select>`
  const selectRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        showSearch
        style={{ width: 200, paddingLeft: 10 }}
        dropdownStyle={{ zIndex: 9999 }}
        placeholder=" Fuzzy Search"
        optionFilterProp="children"
        ref={selectRef}
        showAction={['focus']}
        autoFocus={true}
      >
        <Select.Option key="blue">Blue</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option key="red">Red</Select.Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You'll notice that, in addition to using a `ref` I had to make one other significant change - changing two arguments on the `<Select>` component:

```
showAction={['focus']}
autoFocus={true}
```

This is because without them, it will move the cursor, but will fail to trigger the dropdown and the "fancy" select menu; see [issue #8269](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8269) for details.

---

### Sandbox Link

[codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65071488-t89q0](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65071488-t89q0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks - will implement this and let you know what I find. I did find I think a more hacky way by explicitly getting the elementId and using vanilla but probably worth a refactor!

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to open the dropdown on focus, use the `onFocus` & `onBlur` methods to set/unset a key in the state and use that key as the value for `autoFocus`.

```
onFocus = {() => this.setState({ isSelectFocussed: true })}
onBlur = {() => this.setState({ isSelectFocussed: false })}
showAction = "focus"
autoFocus = { this.state.isSelectFocussed }
```